# How To Merge A Column With Adjacent Column Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop a name range column 3, I'm trying to clear each cell in that column but at the same time merge column 3 with column 4. I'm having a hard time. Any help would be great!

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("myNameRange").Columns(3).Cells
    If c.MergeArea.Count < 2 Then
        c.Value = ""
        'need help merging column 3 n 4
    End If
Next
```

Comment: **Just a tip**: You should avoid merging cells *when you can*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to merge c with the column next to it. Is that all you're trying to do?

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("myNameRange").Columns(3).Cells
    If c.MergeArea.Count < 2 Then
        c.Value = ""
        'need help merging column 3 n 4
        Range(c, c.offset(0,1)).Merge


    End If
Next
```